# Object not accessible in the java code

Tags: java

We are working on data mining project.The problem is the object Mode is not accessible in the specified code. Can anyone explain problems in the code?

```
try{
                String query = "select algm from accuracy where id=1";
                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                alg = rs.getString("algm");
                pst.execute();
                pst.close();

   }catch(Exception e1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e1);
            }
            if(alg.equals("DecisionStump"))
            {
                DecisionStump Mode = new DecisionStump();

            }
                else if(alg.equals("NaiveBayes"))
                {
                    NaiveBayes Mode = new NaiveBayes();

                }

            // filter for removing samples:
            Remove rm = new Remove();
            rm.setAttributeIndices("1"); // remove 1st attribute

            // filtered classifier
            FilteredClassifier fc = new FilteredClassifier();
            fc.setFilter(rm);
            fc.setClassifier(Mode); //This object Mode is not accesible
```

Comment: Can you show the package Name of `FilteredClassifier` maybe it must be `FilteredClassifier.MODE`?

Comment: weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.FilteredClassifier()

Comment: code is block specific can't accessible outside.

Comment: By Java language conventions, use lowercase names for variables. Also, read up on variable scoping, and use appropriate tagd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the `Mode` object inside the if or else if statement and using the same in context outside where its no longer available (Block scope).

You can do the following:

```
Classifier Mode; // a parent class
if(alg.equals("DecisionStump")) {
  Mode = new DecisionStump();
} else if(alg.equals("NaiveBayes")) {
  Mode = new NaiveBayes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The identifier `Mode` is being declared in a local block that immediately exit's scope.

```
        Classifier mode
        if(alg.equals("DecisionStump"))
        {
            mode = new DecisionStump();

        }
        else if(alg.equals("NaiveBayes"))
        {
            mode = new NaiveBayes();
        }
```

Comment: There are many things in life that I dont understand! Now, downvote to this answer is one of them.

Comment: This downvote I think was for the question. Somebody downvoted the answer..:P

Comment: @codeMan, for as little as one upvote, you could negate 5 things you don't understand. Personally, I think some people take the gaming incentives of reputation too seriously.